# Admob v-2 trouble

Tags: android, lua, admob, coronasdk

I am having some trouble adding admob ads to my program.

This is my build.settings: http://pastebin.com/pXL9zxua
and this is my relevant code: http://pastebin.com/f8LzE46Q .
I get the error: "warning the 'ads' library is not available on this platform" when running on the simulator, and the ads are not displaying when the program is run on my android device either.

any ideas?

Written in LUA using Corona SDK.

Comment: Put all the relevant code in question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Corona simulator does not support ads, so no hope there... Android simulator takes like 10-20-30 requests in order to start showing ads... its admob problem. Just open your app let it initialize call show ad, then close and kill from tasks, then do it again, and again, and again... it will eventually show up

Comment: turns out the appID was incorrect, I fixed that and now I am receiving this error : "ad request successful but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory".
even in testmode, and in testmode the test ads should appear anyways right?